# Wordpress All in one calendar - Overlaps in events in week view

Tags: wordpress, all-in-one-event-calendar

We are using the all in one Calendar from Wordpress and have it set to week view (only this view). Everything is working fine, but there is one problem when you have set two events to the same time. There is an overlaps in the two events and you can not see one of the two. We can not change it in css and did not find a way to modify the code.

In the code the css is automaticly made, for instance to:

top  1185px
height 60px
left 8px

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok we did find the answer for this question:

Open week.php (in the template file) and look for the code
   left: px;

The 8 is the 8px left and because it is just 8px you can not see the event behind it. We changed it to 30 so:

left: px;

Now we can see the other event